# JPA: Named Query on inherited JPA Entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa, single-table-inheritance

I have a entity `University` having a list of abstract `Person`. There are two implementations `Student` and `Professor`. Now I would like to find all Universities without any Student by a JPA Query.

University-Class

```
@Entity
public class University {
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Person.class,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            mappedBy = "university",
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Abstract Person class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Person {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private University university;

}
```

Student Implementation

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("STUDENT")
public class Student extends Person {

    @NotNull
    private String matriculation;
}
```

A native SQL query would be as following. But I have no idea how to translate that to a JPA Named Query or - also ok - in Criteria API.

```
select *
from university
    where id not in (
        select distinct u.id
        from university u
            join person p on u.id = p.university_id
            where p.type = 'STUDENT'
    )
;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error saying class not mapped with named query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846658/getting-error-saying-class-not-mapped-with-named-query)

Answer (score 0):

the implementation with criteria look like this:

```
// Define the objects from criteria
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<University> cq = cb.createQuery(University.class);

// From clause
Root<University> rootUniversity = cq.from(University.class);

//Create subquery assuming that the university has an ID (which is mandatory) and is of type Long
Subquery<Long> sq = cq.subquery(Long.class);
Root<University> sqRootUniversity = sq.from(University.class);
Join<University,Person> sqJoinPerson =  sqRootUniversity.join(University_.persons,JoinType.INNER);
sq.where(cb.equal(sqJoinPerson.get(Person_.type),"STUDENT"));
sq.select(sqRootUniversity.get(University_.id)).distinct(true);

//Add subquery to where
cq.where(rootUniversity.get(University_.id).in(sq.getSelection()).not());

// Select clause
cq.select(rootUniversity);

//Get results
List<University> universities = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846658/getting-error-saying-class-not-mapped-with-named-query).

You just need to use `@NamedQuery` or `@NamedNativeQuery`:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery( name="<your-query-name>" , query="SELECT p FROM Person p")
 })

@Entity(name="Person")
@Table(name="person")
public abstract class Person {
```